# What Are the Differences Between the Vim Text Objects ip and ap?

Tags: vim, neovim

The Vim Handbook gives them both the exact same description. From the Vim Handbook:

> `ap`: "a paragraph", select [count] paragraphs. Exception: a blank line (only containing white space) is also a paragraph boundary. When used in Visual mode it is made linewise.

> `ip`: "inner paragraph", select [count] paragraphs. Exception: a blank line (only containing white space) is also a paragraph boundary. When used in Visual mode it is made linewise.

Because of this, it is not entirely clear to me what the differences between these are. For example, say you had the commands `gqap` and `gqip`. How do they differ in behaviour?

Comment: I agree the document is not clear. You can try  `vap` vs `vip` to see the different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Again, just reading `:help ap` because someone gave you the link, without proper background, will get you nowhere and only bring more confusion.

Text objects can be of two types: those that *include* their boundaries and those that *exclude* their boundaries.

By convention, text objects that include their boundaries start with `a`, like `ap`, and those that exclude their boundaries start with `i`, like `ip`.

What constitutes a "paragraph" is explained under `:help paragraph`, which is linked from both `:help ip` and `:help ap`. In concrete terms, the boundaries of a paragraph are:

- a non-empty line preceded by an empty one, think of it as zero-width match,
- the next empty line.

So you have `ip`, which excludes the empty line, and `ap`, which includes it:

```
[...] end of paragraph above.

Beginning of paragraph in the middle    |       |
with some boring filler text so that    | ip    | ap
it covers a few lines.                  |       |
                                                |
Beginning of paragraph below [...]
```

When doing `gq` over a paragraph, using `ip` or `ap` doesn't really matter because the extra empty line is unlikely to change anything to what is being done to the text. `ip` and `ap` are a bit of an exception, here, because the difference between the two types of text objects usually matters quite a lot:

```
             it
    ----------------------
<h2>One day I will be a H1</h2>
-------------------------------
             at
```

See `:help text-objects` for a reference on the subject and `:help 04.8` for a more gentle introduction.

As alluded to in my other answer, proper learning lets you develop an intuition that is hard to build from random, disconnected, links and tweets and so on.